# Move UIImageView in uiimagepickercontroller cameraoverlayview

Tags: ios, cameraoverlayview

I have uiimagepickercontroller with cameraoverlayview

in view cameraOverlay ,i have uiimageview.

How do move and scale uiimageview in cameraOverlay.

My code

// create the overlay view

```
overlayView = [[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+90)];

// important - it needs to be transparent so the camera preview shows through!
overlayView.opaque=NO;
overlayView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

// parent view for our overlay
UIView *cameraView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+90)];
[cameraView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cameraView addSubview:overlayView];

Layer=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 100, self.view.frame.size.width-300, self.view.frame.size.height-250)];
Layer.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"layer.png"];
[Layer setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cameraView addSubview:Layer];
[CameraImagePickerController setCameraOverlayView:cameraView];

[self presentViewController:CameraImagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I want move and scale Layer

Comment: did not get your question .explain some more

Comment: @Sport do you any answers my question ?